# ¿Cómo puedo dar solución a este problema? non-static variable lista

Tags: java

Este es mi código:

```
public class ListaPersonas{
    
    ArrayList<Persona> lista = new ArrayList();
                   
    public static void agregar(Persona persona){                       
        lista.add(persona);
    }
}
```

Este es el error que se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: O haces que la variable `lista` sea estática o haces que el método `agregar()` sea de instancia. El error se refiere a eso, no se puede llamar un miembro de instancia desde un contexto estático.

Answer (score 0):

El error que indicas:

> non-static variable lista cannot be referenced from a static context

indica que la variable lista no puede ser llamada dentro de un método estatico, si deseas llamarla debes usar el modificador static para que la variable lista sea estatica y pueda usarse dentro del método.

```
   static ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();

   public static void agregar(Producto persona){   
       lista.add(persona);
   }
```

> modificador `static`: Sirve para crear miembros que pertenecen a la
> clase, y no a una instancia de la clase. Esto implica, entre otras
> cosas, que no es necesario crear un objeto de la clase para poder
> acceder a estos atributos y métodos.